# Is it safe to use stain and polyurethane on a wooden trivet

Tags: woodworking

I'm making wooden trivets (using hard woods) to sell. I would like to use stain & polyurethane but I'm not sure if it will melt or become damaged when a hot pan is placed on it. Will it be safe?

Comment: Poly will get damaged from the hot pans set on it. A type of oil rubbed in may be better. A light coat of tung oil may do the trick

Comment: @Jack, you should post your comment as an answer.

Comment: I will do so, since it is recommended. I did not at first since the finish I mentioned was not a sure thing.

Answer (score 2):

Oil-based polyurethane is fairly resistant to heat (slightly more so than water-based), and it would seal well, allowing for easier cleaning and care. If you're not a terrible cook or one inclined toward flaming dishes, it should last well.

> For trivets, the enemies are heat and food or water spills. Years ago, I made some trivets for the magazine and finished them with a 50/50 mix of oil-based polyurethane and mineral spirits. Its thinner consistency allowed the finish to flow down into the nooks and crannies well (my trivets had some intricate cutouts, as you can see in the photo below). Then, the excess was easy to wipe off. It soaked in and dried quickly, and I applied several coats. Over the years, we’ve continued to use this very trivet regularly, and the finish has held up well to all sorts of hot pots and cookie sheets. I recommend it.

[More info](http://www.woodworkersjournal.com/finishing-trivets-tung-oil/)

Answer (score 1):

Poly will get damaged from the hot pans set on it. A type of oil rubbed in may be better. A light coat of tung oil may do the trick.

Comment: Be aware that some products marketed as tung oil are actually blends of varnish or urethane and tung oils.

Comment: Wrong, polyurethane is heat resistant.

http://dalchem.com.au/how-to/facts-about-polyurethane/

Comment: Above comment was changed from an edit attempt by a new member and made more palatable. Otherwise it was very rude.